# empty href not displaying as link

Tags: html, href, mouseover

I'm no programmer, so this might be really messy. Maybe there's a cleaner method to create a mouseover pop-up?

I'm using an empty href to create a mouse over pop-up. My issue is that the empty href is not displaying as a link, so there is no indication that one should mouseover.

```
(<a href=" " title="Infrastructure, comprising a society's ... , and science (symbolic and ideational relations)."></a><span title="Infrastructure, comprising a society's ... , and science (symbolic and ideational relations)."><i>'Infrastructural, Structural and Superstructural'</i></span>
```

I also tried: javascript:void(0); javascript:; and #  (all to no avail); I finally settled for italics- but that is no real cue.

Comment: Why do you want it to look like a link if it is not a (real) link? It’s poor usability.

Answer (score 0):

[If you just want the pop-over title, you can put that on any element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#title) without having to use an empty (and non-semantic) `a` link.

Plus, considering your `a` tag is empty nothing will be rendered, so no link will be seen.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, I think your  tags should be around the text.

```
<a href="#" title="Infrastructure, comprising a society's ... , and science (symbolic and ideational relations)."><span title="Infrastructure, comprising a society's ... , and science (symbolic and ideational relations)."><i>'Infrastructural, Structural and Superstructural'</i></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close - but you need to know that `<a href='...'>` opens the tag and `</a>` closes it. The text between those two is the bit that show up underlined.

```
<a href="#" title="Blah de blah blah">Blah</a>
```

or...

```
<span style="color:blue" title="The definition of the term">the term used</span>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Incorrect placement of the </a> tag was an oversight on my part. BTW, if you use <a href="#", clicking on the link sends you to the top of the page; href="javascript:void(0) does nothing.